# How to transform a time column (with hours and minutes) from data type "object" to a time/datetime type?

Tags: python, datetime, time

beginner here, at the Moment I prepare data to create a neural net. For this reason I have a Pandas dataframe with several columns. One of these columns shows the time of the day in 15 min steps (00:00, 00:15, 00:30, …, 23:45, 00:00, 00:15, …) The data type of this column is object. How can I transform it to a time-related datatype?

I tried this, but it adds (wrong) year-month-day Information to the column

```
Erzeugung["uhrzeit"] = pd.to_datetime(Erzeugung["uhrzeit"])

(2019-07-22 00:00:00, 2019-07-22 00:15:00, …)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strftime function to keep only the desired parts of your datetime object.

```
pd.to_datetime('14-08-92 23:15:00').strftime('%H:%M')
```

> '23:15'

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I tried it like this:
Erzeugung["uhrzeit"] = pd.to_datetime(Erzeugung["uhrzeit"]).strftime('%H:%M')
But I get an error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
What does that mean or how can I solve this?

Comment: Write this instead:

Erzeugung["uhrzeit"] = pd.to_datetime(Erzeugung["uhrzeit"].values).strftime('%H:%M')

Let me know if this doesn't work. Now strftime will be applied to an array, rather than a pandas series.

Comment: It's still marked as an object. Maybe as a for-loop? Something like this?
```
>>>zeit = []
>>>for i in range(0, len(Erzeugung"uhrzeit")):
    zeit.append(pd.to_datetime(Erzeugung["uhrzeit"].values).strftime("%H:%M"))
>>>Erzeugung["uhrzeit"] = zeit

Comment: Okay this is an infinity loop